# The Battle of Gog and Magog

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, tanach

Very little is known about The Battle of Gog and Magog, it is shroud in mystery and countless debates. The prophet Ezekiel (chapters 38-39) describes the battle and the prophet Zachariya (chapter 14) describes the battle's outcome - the ultimate victory of G-d and the Hebrews. While the vast majority of the chapter deals with the outcome, the second verse deals with the suffering of Jerusalem's residents, to quote:

> For I will gather all nations against Jerusalem to battle; and the
>   city shall be taken, and the houses rifled, and the women ravished;
>   and half of the city shall go forth into captivity, but the residue of
>   the people shall not be cut off from the city.

While I have no doubt that the battle of Gog and Magog along with it's atrocities and horrors is part of G-ds master plan, I have an extremely hard time comprehending the intense suffering on the brink of redemption. Suffering that even the final redemption will not cure! Can you imagine, all of Jerusalem's women will be ravished!!!

I'm not questioning G-d or his ways, but is there a way to understand and come to peace with this horror?

Comment: Hey cheer-up! Don't you know that all the prophecies are metaphorical? G-d said to Avraham 400 years of slavery it was only 86 and many more examples. We can always solve it retroactively by saying "Oh, since every Jew is a whole world, so if one Israeli tourist was complaining about being raped in Cyprus, that like the prophecy was fulfilled". We should only be seriously worried that *some* will not turn this prophecy into self-fulfilling!

Comment: I think it's a good question but you must rephrase it to state the question more clearly.

Comment: "וּפְעָמִים אוֹמְרִים הַמָּשָׁל בִּלְבַד בְּלֹא פִּתְרוֹן כְּמִקְצָת דִּבְרֵי יְחֶזְקֵאל וּזְכַרְיָה וְכֻלָּן בְּמָשָׁל וְדֶרֶךְ חִידָה הֵם מִתְנַבְּאִים:" https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.7?lang=he

Comment: I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: Interestingly, the only way G-d sees to solve the world's problems is just more violence. I'd agree that some would expect from the almighty and all-benevolent something more peaceful and friendly, but I think that's the only language Tanach knows - everybody is our enemies, all they want is to destruct us and all we can do is to fight back. Can't we just break this circle?

Comment: What’s the question

Comment: @Al Berko We will, eventually

Comment: @JoeHoward The battle between Gog and Magog is a metaphorical battle between the self. There is no real war involved. Rambam wrote in his Mishneh Torah that we should not expect a change in nature to occur in the messianic age. The Jewish redemption is not as epic as Revelation in John so we don’t get too many Hollywood movies. Anyway only positive predictions will take place, not negative ones.

Comment: @AlBerko A careful reading of the Torah will show that we were under Egyptian captivity for more than 86 years. We were slaves for 400 years.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?